# Computer Science - Stack Exchange: FAQ

Tags: discussion, site-faq

Well, we are almost at the 90 days threshold. Let's have another try to write our FAQ.

To avoid the pitfalls of the previous [attempt](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168/7-essential-meta-questions-faq), please post entries for FAQ as answers. We can later select and combine some of the answers to create the site's FAQ and this post can serve as a place for a larger FAQ (like [math.se](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107), [SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), [cstheory main](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science), [cstheory supplement](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25/material-to-supplement-the-faq)).

Since this is Frequently Asked *Questions*, try to start your FAQ entry by a question (and don't post several entries in a single question). If you want to have extended discussion about a posted FAQ entry start a new meta-discussion (or chat) and post a comment linking to the discussion below the question.

Answer (score 2):

#### What kind of questions can I ask here? (what is included)

[Computer Science - Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) is a Q&A site for computer scientists and people interested in *computer science*. We welcome computer science questions from **students**, **researchers**, and **practitioners**.

Computer science here is defined in the general sense, including topics like

- Algorithms and Data Structures
- Artificial Intelligence
- Computational Linguistics and Natural Language Processing
- Computer Vision
- Computer Networks and Internet Architecture
- Computer Architecture
- Computer Graphics
- Databases
- Human-Computer Interaction
- Knowledge Representation and Reasoning
- Machine Learning
- Operating Systems
- Programming Languages
- Software Engineering
- Theoretical Computer Science

---

Related discussions:

- [How to make our cs community very different from the cstheory?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78/how-to-make-our-cs-community-very-different-from-the-cstheory)
- [Should questions about other sciences for computer scientists be on topic?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260/should-questions-about-other-sciences-for-computer-scientists-be-on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

#### What kind of questions can I ask here? (what is excluded)

However *programming and software development questions* are more suitable for [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and [Software Engineering](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com). Please post your programming and software development questions on them.

Questions that are not scientific but rather about managing and using computers should be posted on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or other [relevant SE sites](http://stackexchange.com).

Questions about *academics* and *careers* which are not specific to computer science should be posted on [Academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com).

*Mathematical* questions without explicit computer science motivation or relation should be posted on [Mathematics](http://mathematics.stackexchange.com).

If you have a question about the site, please ask on [meta](http://meta.cs.sackexchange.com) instead.

---

Related discussions:

- [Career questions](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240/career-questions)
- [Are programming questions in scope on CS.SE?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/254/)

Answer (score 1):

#### Can I ask my homework questions here?

According to [our policy](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/468/homework-policy), there is no special treatment on this site regarding homework questions.

If you let others solve your homework, you are cheating mostly yourself. So we recommend you make a serious attempt yourself which should be included in your question in order to make it a good one. Keep in mind that you can ask answerers to give you hints rather than full answers.

---

Related Discussions:

- [Homework tag discussion](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17/homework-tag-discussion)
- [Will homework questions be allowed?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/will-homework-questions-be-allowed)
- [What should the homework tag mean?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313/what-should-the-homework-tag-mean)
- [Just-a-hint tag](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177/just-a-hint-tag)

Answer (score 0):

#### What kind of questions can I ask here? (what is better off elsewhere)

Some questions are ontopic, but you may get better answers on specialised sites.

Research-level theoretical computer science questions are the focus on [Theoretical Computer Science - Stack Exchange](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com).

Scientific computing in all its flavors is discussed on [Computational Science - Stack Exchange](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com).

Statistics, machine learning and data mining are at home on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com).